# Django rest framework + ionic2 + django channels

Tags: django-rest-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2, django-channels

I want to develop real time native application and considering using Django as backend and ionic2 as frontend. But through the research i realize that websocket is needed for the app to be real-time. And django channels is the option.

The question is "is it possible to combinate django rest framework, ionic2 and django channels altogether?" And additionally if I try to implement push notification using cordova plugin, could it be also work altogether? I know this question is quite bad but I am quite a beginner so i want to know before trying this approach..

any advice will be great for me, Thanks buddies in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. 
Ionic is going to be only a consumer of your Django-rest-framework API and your Django services. In other words, the front-end can be in any technology you want.

On the other side, Django-rest-framework + Channels work perfectly together. They are supposed to be. I've recently built a project with those technologies and I can guarantee that there is a perfect separation between the asynchronous processes and the typical Django HTTP runserver process.

Comment: We are just now having issues in Ionic when connecting to the websockets, having a problem establishing connections. From the browser it works just fine. Have you experienced anything similar?

Comment: @JorgeDLuffy I know this is a really old post but is it possible that you could share the repo for your project that involved integrating both channels and drf? If it's not possible, can you recommend a guide on where to start?